# Task.Parallel.For doesn't seem to be running parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

This piece of code is supposed to send between 2 and 7 requests to get data simultaneously to reduce wait time. On my computer the code was taking 6 seconds to run. When I uploaded it to Azure it takes 60 seconds. If I open 2 windows of the Azure version and run them side by side they take 120 seconds. It seems to me that they are either not running simultaneously like I wanted or that the multiple calls at the same time are bottlenecking the server. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
List<string> strs = new List<string>();
Parallel.For(0, uriArray.Count(), index =>
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync(uriArray[index]).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = response.Content;
            var responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

            using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(responseString, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
            using (StreamReader unzip = new StreamReader(zip))
            {
                strs.Add(unzip.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How many cores you have in your machine ?

Comment: @Shyju my computer has 8

Comment: What about in Azure?

Comment: the VM only has 1

Comment: There's not much point in calling an async method if you're just going to block on it by immediately calling `Result`.

Comment: @juharr there is a point: Parallel.For requires a synchronous API. It's a small inefficiency. It's very unfashionable, but fine.

Comment: @usr Then just call the synchronous methods instead.  Or really don't bother with parallelism when doing IO.

Comment: @juharr HttpClient does not have synchronous methods. If it had, and I think it should, your comment would apply.

Answer (score 1):

The `Parallel.*` methods are meant for CPU bound work because they use CPU based heuristics to choose the degree of parallelism. For IO-based work these heuristics fail completely. The optimal DOP for IO *must* be determined empirically. It cannot be derived from the number of CPU cores.

> the VM only has 1

There you go. On a smaller VM you'll be making HTTP calls less frequently which clearly is nonsense because HTTP calls consume little CPU.

Use the last piece of code from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/ to process your work items with a fixed degree of parallelism. As an added benefit you can loose the `.Result` calls.

The .NET Framework shamefully has nothing built-in which is why you have to use this code from the blog.